# Issues with returning values from nested axios call in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

The below function does not return any value when the lenght of the output from the first call. I have given comment in the line of code that is creating issues in the below snippet. Can you please advise what is the issue with my code?

```
async createProfileByUserIDNew(data,email) {
        const AuthStr = 'Bearer ' + getToken();
        const response = await axios
            .get(`${baseUrl}/profiles?email=${email}`, {
                headers: { Authorization: AuthStr },
            })
            .then((response) => {                
                if (response.data.length===0){
                    return  axios
                    .post(`${baseUrl}/buyer-profiles`, data, {
                        headers: { Authorization: AuthStr },
                    })                    
                }else{     
                    console.log(response.data);  // Printing the proper results             
                    return response.data, // not returning any results to next then.Return statement not working
                    }                    
                }                
            }).then((response) => {
                return{
                    items: response.data, // returning proper results for if statement but failing for else condition
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => (console.log( JSON.stringify(error)) ));      
    }
      ///calling the nested axios call
      const ret = MyProfileRepository.createProfileByUserIDNew(
                data,
                user.email
            );
            ret.then(function (response) {
                console.log(response); //Printing 'undefined'
                This.setState({ buyerProfileId: response.items.id });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `createProfileByUserIDNew` is an `async` function, meaning you need a `return` statement:

```js
async function createProfileByUserIDNew() {
    const AuthStr = 'Bearer ' + getToken();
    const response = await axios.get(...).etc;
    return response;
}
```

Alternatively, you can also directly return a promise:

```js
async function createProfileByUserIDNew() {
    const AuthStr = 'Bearer ' + getToken();
    return axios.get(...).etc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have only one `.then` callback function. Here is the correct implementation

```
async createProfileByUserIDNew(data,email) {
        const AuthStr = 'Bearer ' + getToken();
        const response = await axios
            .get(`${baseUrl}/profiles?email=${email}`, {
                headers: { Authorization: AuthStr },
            })
            .then((response) => {                
                if (response.data.length===0){
                    return  axios
                    .post(`${baseUrl}/buyer-profiles`, data, {
                        headers: { Authorization: AuthStr },
                    }).then((response) => {
                return{
                    items: response.data, // returning proper results.working as expected
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => (console.log( JSON.stringify(error)) ));      
    }                    
                }else{     
                    console.log(response.data[0]);  // Printing the proper results             
                    return{
                        items: response.data[0], // not returning any results.Return statement not working
                    }                    
                }                
            })
```

But you can improve your conditions but for the sake of argument, this code will work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you return from your first `then` function, the promise falls through to the second `then` function.  The `else` condition of your first function returns an object shaped as `{ items: data }` while the second `then` function is expecting a response object, not an object w/ an `items` key.

You could handle this in a few ways:

1. You're defining an `async` function, but you're not doing anything asynchronously (in terms of ES6 syntax).  You could convert your whole function to this syntax to async/await properly within your conditional statements.
2. You could convert your first `then` to an async function, then asynchronously fetch the second request from there.
3. You could change the structure of what you return in the `else` condition so that it looks like a response object, and can be parsed properly in the secondary `then` function.

In addition, you are not returning the `response` promise.

## Solution 1

```
async createProfileByUserIDNew(data, email) {
  const AuthStr = 'Bearer ' + getToken();

  try {
    let response = axios.get(`${baseUrl}/profiles?email=${email}`, {
      headers: { Authorization: AuthStr },
    });
  
    if (response.data.length === 0) {
      response = await axios.post(`${baseUrl}/buyer-profiles`, data, {
        headers: { Authorization: AuthStr },
      });
    }

    return {
      items: response.data[0],
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
}
```

## Solution 2

```
createProfileByUserIDNew(data,email) {
  const AuthStr = 'Bearer ' + getToken();
  return axios
    .get(`${baseUrl}/profiles?email=${email}`, {
      headers: { Authorization: AuthStr },
    })
    .then(async (response) => {                
      if (response.data.length === 0) {
        response = await axios
          .post(`${baseUrl}/buyer-profiles`, data, {
            headers: { Authorization: AuthStr },
          });
      }
      return {
        items: response.data[0],
      };
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}
```

## Solution 3

```
createProfileByUserIDNew(data,email) {
  const AuthStr = 'Bearer ' + getToken();
  return axios
    .get(`${baseUrl}/profiles?email=${email}`, {
      headers: { Authorization: AuthStr },
    })
    .then((response) => {                
      if (response.data.length === 0) {
        return axios
          .post(`${baseUrl}/buyer-profiles`, data, {
            headers: { Authorization: AuthStr },
          });
      } else {
        return {
          response: {
            data: {
              items: response.data[0],
            },
          },
        };
      }                
    }).then((response) => {
      return {
        items: response.data,
      };
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you please show the changes required in my code?Appreciated your support